# How to get list of application icons which are installed in device with Qt

Tags: qt, symbian, qicon

I am working with Qt application in which I want to create a QListWidget with names of all application installed on device and its icon.
So I was unable get all application names and UID of each application from the code in this [LINK](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/05/symbianqt-get-list-of-installed.html).
But I was also unable to get the application icons. I tried both this [LINK1](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Get_application_icon) & [LINK2](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_get_Application_Icon_using_RApaLsSession) but here I came across few more issues like how to convert CGulIcon into QIcon & CApaMaskedBitmap into QIcon.

How can I do this?

Comment: please refer all the three links before giving any answer and the code in that link wont compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to get the solution or have any more doubts [click here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10629/agarwal) for disscussion.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "GetInstalledApps.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GetInstalledApps w;
    w.showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = GetInstalledApps 

QT        += core \
    gui 

HEADERS   += GetInstalledApps.h
SOURCES   += main.cpp \
    GetInstalledApps.cpp
FORMS     += GetInstalledApps.ui
RESOURCES +=

HEADERS += xqinstaller_p.h \
   xqinstaller.h \

SOURCES += xqinstaller_p.cpp \
   xqinstaller.cpp

symbian:LIBS += -lswinstcli \
   -lcommdb \
   -lapparc \
   -lefsrv \
   -lapgrfx \


symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY += TrustedUI
symbian:TARGET.UID3 = 0xEF3055F4
```

**GetInstalledApps.h**

```
#ifndef GETINSTALLEDAPPS_H
#define GETINSTALLEDAPPS_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_GetInstalledApps.h"
#include "xqinstaller.h"

class GetInstalledApps : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GetInstalledApps(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GetInstalledApps();

private:
    void GetApps();
    
private:
    Ui::GetInstalledAppsClass ui;
    XQInstaller* m_installer;
    QMap<QString, uint> m_applications;
    QList<QString> m_appNames;
    QList<uint> m_appUID;
};

#endif // GETINSTALLEDAPPS_H
```

**GetInstalledApps.cpp**

```
#include "GetInstalledApps.h"
#include <QScrollArea>

GetInstalledApps::GetInstalledApps(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("GetAllInstalledApps");
    m_installer = new XQInstaller(this);
    GetApps();
    
}

void GetInstalledApps::GetApps()
{
    /* Get List of applications. 
     * type of m_applications is QMap<QString, uint>.
     * type of  m_installer is XQInstaller
     */
    m_applications = m_installer->applications();
    
    /* Get List of application names
     type of m_appNames is QList<QString> */
    m_appNames = m_applications.keys(); 
    
    /* Get List of application UID in decimal. 
    type of m_appUID is QList<uint> */
    m_appUID = m_applications.values(); 
    
    ui.listWidget->clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_appNames.count(); i++) 
    {
        QString str;
        /* convert UID from decimal to hex and then string. */
        str.setNum(m_appUID.at(i),16);
        /* append name and UID to string */     
        QString string(m_appNames.at(i)+"  UID:"+ str);
        /* append string to list widget to display on screen */
        ui.listWidget->addItem(string);
    }
    
    /* Let's make the UI scale so that we can scroll it. */
    QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setWidget(ui.listWidget);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

    setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
}

GetInstalledApps::~GetInstalledApps()
{

}
```

**xqinstaller.h**

```
#ifndef XQINSTALLER_H
#define XQINSTALLER_H

// INCLUDES
#include <QObject>
#include <QMap>

class XQInstallerPrivate;

// CLASS DECLARATION
class XQInstaller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum Error {
        NoError = 0,
        OutOfMemoryError,
        AlreadyInUseError,
        UserCancelError, 
        PackageNotSupportedError,
        SecurityFailureError,
        MissingDependencyError,
        NoRightsError,
        BusyError,
        AccessDeniedError,
        UpgradeError,
        UnknownError = -1
    };
    
    enum Drive {
        DriveA,   DriveB,   DriveC,   DriveD,   DriveE,
        DriveF,   DriveG,   DriveH,   DriveI,   DriveJ,
        DriveK,   DriveL,   DriveM,   DriveN,   DriveO, 
        DriveP,   DriveQ,   DriveR,   DriveS,   DriveT,
        DriveU,   DriveV,   DriveW,   DriveX,   DriveY,
        DriveZ
    };

    XQInstaller(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~XQInstaller();
    
    bool install(const QString& file, XQInstaller::Drive drive = XQInstaller::DriveC);
    QMap<QString, uint> applications() const;
    bool remove(uint uid);

    XQInstaller::Error error() const;
    
Q_SIGNALS:
    void applicationInstalled();
    void applicationRemoved();
    void error(XQInstaller::Error);
    
private:
    friend class XQInstallerPrivate;
    XQInstallerPrivate *d;
};

#endif // XQINSTALLER_H
```

**xqinstaller.cpp**

```
#include "xqinstaller.h"
#include "xqinstaller_p.h"

/*!
    \class XQInstaller
    \brief The XQInstaller class is used to install sis-packages silently. 
    This extension can be used for example to install back-end applications.

    Example:
    \code
    XQInstaller *installer = new XQInstaller(this);
    QMap<QString, uint> applications = installer->applications();
    QListWidget *applicationList = new QListWidget(this);
    QList<QString> appNames = applications.keys();
    for (int i = 0; i < appNames.count(); i++) {
        applicationList->addItem(appNames.at(i));
    }   
    \endcode
*/

/*!
    Constructs a XQInstaller object with the given parent.
    \sa install(), remove()
*/
XQInstaller::XQInstaller(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), d(new XQInstallerPrivate(this))
{
}

/*!
    Destroys the XQInstaller object.
*/
XQInstaller::~XQInstaller()
{
    delete d;
}

/*!
    Installs a sis package silently given as parameter.

    \param file Sis package
    \param drive Drive letter where the sis is installed to. Default value is 'C'.
    \return If false is returned, an error has occurred. Call error() to get a value of 
    XQInstaller::Error that indicates which error occurred
    \sa error()
*/  
bool XQInstaller::install(const QString& file, XQInstaller::Drive drive)
{
    return d->install(file, drive);
}

/*!
    Get list of installed applications
    If an empty QMap is returned, an error has possibly occurred. Call error() to get a value of 
    XQInstaller::Error that indicates which error occurred if any
    
    \return List of installed applications
    \sa error()
*/
QMap<QString, uint> XQInstaller::applications() const
{
    return d->applications();
}

/*!
    Removes application specified by the uid
   
    \param uid of the application
    \return True if removing was successfully started, otherwise false
    \sa error()
*/
bool XQInstaller::remove(uint uid)
{
    return d->remove(uid);
}

/*!
    \enum XQInstaller::Error

    This enum defines the possible errors for a XQInstaller object.
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::NoError
    No error occured.
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::OutOfMemoryError
    Not enough memory.
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::AlreadyInUseError
    Installer is already in used.
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::UserCancelError
    Installer cancelled by the user.
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::PackageNotSupportedError
    Package not supported
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::SecurityFailureError
    Security failure
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::MissingDependencyError
    Missing dependency
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::NoRightsError
    No rights
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::BusyError
    Installer is busy
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::AccessDeniedError
    Access denied
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::UpgradeError
    Error while upgrading
*/
/*! \var XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::UnknownError
    Unknown error.
*/

/*!
    Returns the type of error that occurred if the latest function call failed; otherwise returns NoError
    \return Error code
*/
XQInstaller::Error XQInstaller::error() const
{
    return d->error();
}

/*!
    \fn void XQInstaller::applicationInstalled()

    This signal is emitted when the application has been installed.

    \sa install()
*/

/*!
    \fn void XQInstaller::error(XQInstaller::Error)

    This signal is emitted if error occured during the asynchronous operation

    \sa install()
*/

/*!
    \fn void XQInstaller::applicationRemoved()

    This signal is emitted when the application has been removed.

    \sa remove()
*/

// End of file
```

**xqinstaller_h.h**

```
#ifndef XQINSTALLER_P_H
#define XQINSTALLER_P_H

// INCLUDES
#include "xqinstaller.h"
#include <SWInstApi.h>
#include <SWInstDefs.h>

// FORWARD DECLARATIONS
class QString;
class QFile;

// CLASS DECLARATION
class XQInstallerPrivate: public CActive
{

public:
    enum State {
        ERemove,
        EInstall
    };
    
    XQInstallerPrivate(XQInstaller *installer);
    ~XQInstallerPrivate();
    
    bool install(const QString& file, XQInstaller::Drive drive);
    bool remove(uint uid);
    QMap<QString, uint> applications() const;

public:
    XQInstaller::Error error();
    
protected:  
    void DoCancel();
    void RunL();

private:
    XQInstaller *q;
    mutable int iError;
    
    SwiUI::RSWInstSilentLauncher iLauncher;
    SwiUI::TInstallOptions iOptions;
    SwiUI::TInstallOptionsPckg iOptionsPckg;  
    
    SwiUI::TUninstallOptions iUninstallOptions;
    SwiUI::TUninstallOptionsPckg iUninstallOptionsPckg;
    XQInstallerPrivate::State iState;
    TFileName iFileName;
    bool iLauncherConnected;
};

#endif /*XQINSTALLER_P_H*/

// End of file
```

**xqinstaller_h.cpp**

```
#include "xqinstaller.h"
#include "xqinstaller_p.h"
#include <f32file.h>
#include <apgcli.h>

XQInstallerPrivate::XQInstallerPrivate(XQInstaller *installer) 
    : CActive(EPriorityNormal), q(installer), iOptionsPckg(iOptions), 
      iUninstallOptionsPckg(iUninstallOptions), iLauncherConnected(false)
{
    CActiveScheduler::Add(this);  
}

XQInstallerPrivate::~XQInstallerPrivate()
{
    Cancel();
    if (iLauncherConnected) {
        iLauncher.Close();
    }
}

bool XQInstallerPrivate::install(const QString& file, XQInstaller::Drive drive)
{
    int asciiValue = 10;  // = 'A'
    TRAP(iError,
        if (!iLauncherConnected) {
            User::LeaveIfError(iLauncher.Connect());
            iLauncherConnected = true;
        }
        if (IsActive()) {
            User::Leave(KErrInUse);
        }
        
        iState = XQInstallerPrivate::EInstall;
        iOptions.iUpgrade = SwiUI::EPolicyAllowed;
        iOptions.iOCSP = SwiUI::EPolicyNotAllowed;
        iOptions.iDrive = TChar(asciiValue+drive);
        iOptions.iUntrusted = SwiUI::EPolicyAllowed; 
        iOptions.iCapabilities = SwiUI::EPolicyAllowed;  
        iOptions.iOptionalItems = SwiUI::EPolicyAllowed;  
        iOptions.iOverwrite = SwiUI::EPolicyAllowed; 
        TPtrC16 fileName(reinterpret_cast<const TUint16*>(file.utf16()));
        iFileName = fileName;
        iLauncher.SilentInstall(iStatus, iFileName, iOptionsPckg);
        SetActive();
    )
    return (iError == KErrNone);
}

bool XQInstallerPrivate::remove(uint uid)
{
    TRAP(iError,
        if (!iLauncherConnected) {
            User::LeaveIfError(iLauncher.Connect());
            iLauncherConnected = true;
        }
        if (IsActive()) {
            User::Leave(KErrInUse);
        }

        iState = XQInstallerPrivate::ERemove;
    
        iLauncher.SilentUninstall(iStatus,TUid::Uid(uid),
            iUninstallOptionsPckg, SwiUI::KSisxMimeType);
        SetActive();
    )
    return (iError == KErrNone);
}

QMap<QString, uint> XQInstallerPrivate::applications() const
{
    RApaLsSession lsSession;
    QMap<QString, uint> applications; 
      
    // Connect to application architecture server
    TRAP(iError,
        User::LeaveIfError(lsSession.Connect());
        CleanupClosePushL(lsSession);
        
        TApaAppInfo appInfo;
        lsSession.GetAllApps();  
        
        while (lsSession.GetNextApp(appInfo) == KErrNone) {
            TApaAppCapabilityBuf capability;
            User::LeaveIfError(lsSession.GetAppCapability(capability,
                appInfo.iUid));
            if (appInfo.iCaption.Length() > 0 && !capability().iAppIsHidden) {
                QString fullName = QString::fromUtf16(
                    appInfo.iCaption.Ptr(), appInfo.iCaption.Length());
                applications.insert(fullName, (TUint)appInfo.iUid.iUid);
            }
        }
        CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(&lsSession);
    )
      
    return applications; 
}

void XQInstallerPrivate::DoCancel()
{
    if (iState == XQInstallerPrivate::EInstall) {
        iLauncher.CancelAsyncRequest(SwiUI::ERequestSilentInstall);
    } else if (iState == XQInstallerPrivate::ERemove) {
        iLauncher.CancelAsyncRequest(SwiUI::ERequestSilentUninstall);
    }
}
 
void XQInstallerPrivate::RunL()
{
    if (iStatus.Int() == KErrNone) {
        if (iState == XQInstallerPrivate::EInstall) {
            emit q->applicationInstalled();
        } else if (iState == XQInstallerPrivate::ERemove) {
            emit q->applicationRemoved();
        }
    } else {
        iError = iStatus.Int();
        emit q->error(error());
    }
}

XQInstaller::Error XQInstallerPrivate::error()
{
    switch (iError) {
    case KErrNone:
        return XQInstaller::NoError;
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrInsufficientMemory:
    case KErrNoMemory:
        return XQInstaller::OutOfMemoryError;
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrFileInUse:
    case KErrInUse:
        return XQInstaller::AlreadyInUseError;
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrUserCancel:
        return XQInstaller::UserCancelError;  
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrPackageNotSupported:
        return XQInstaller::PackageNotSupportedError; 
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrSecurityFailure:
        return XQInstaller::SecurityFailureError; 
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrMissingDependency:
        return XQInstaller::MissingDependencyError; 
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrNoRights:
        return XQInstaller::NoRightsError;
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrBusy:
        return XQInstaller::BusyError;
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrAccessDenied:
        return XQInstaller::AccessDeniedError;
    case SwiUI::KSWInstUpgradeError:
        return XQInstaller::UpgradeError;
    case SwiUI::KSWInstErrGeneralError:
    default:
        return XQInstaller::UnknownError;
    }    
}
 
// End of file
```

****And for [getting QIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#fromSymbianCFbsBitmap)::****

**Hearders Required:**

```
#include <fbs.h> //CFbsBitmap
#include <aknsskininstance.h> //MAknsSkinInstance 
#include <aknsutils.h> //AknsUtils
```

**Library required:**

```
LIBRARY   fbscli.lib ///CFbsBitmap
LIBRARY   aknskins.lib aknskinsrv.lib aknswallpaperutils.lib  //MAknsSkinInstance ,AknsUtils
```

Source Code:

```
CGulIcon* CMyClass::GetApplicationIconL(const TUid& aAppUID)
{
    CFbsBitmap* AppIcon(NULL);
    CFbsBitmap* AppIconMsk(NULL);
 
    MAknsSkinInstance* skin = AknsUtils::SkinInstance();
 
    AknsUtils::CreateAppIconLC(skin,aAppUID,  EAknsAppIconTypeContext,AppIcon,AppIconMsk);
    CleanupStack::Pop(2);
 
    return CGulIcon::NewL(AppIcon,AppIconMsk);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, for the icon thing look at this: CGullIcon there's a function that returns the Bitmap, a CFbsBitmap. Once you've done that look at this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#fromSymbianCFbsBitmap then you create a new QIcon(QPixmap) (QPixmap = the icon you've transformed). So most likely you're first passing it to a CFbsBitmap and then with QPixmap you use fromSymibnaCFbsBitmap().

CApaMaskedBitmap is a sub-class of CFbsBitmap if i'm not wrong, so it should work the same.

And for getting the applications and their UID try to look at this: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Get_list_of_installed_applications_and_its_UID_in_Qt

Comment: Sorry, can't add too much hyperlinks, as i have low rep still. :/

Comment: -1 the link for getting app names and uid is same which is mentioned in the question and which wont compile even.

Comment: Have you tryed using TApaAppInfo?

Comment: yes i tried but unable to understand anything. If you have any sample/working code then update it.